# Unity Engine Perception Package

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, synthetic

I am Using perception package for the Synthetic Data generation. I want to Create a Custom Scenario since the built in "Fixed length Scenario" runs as soon the program starts but i want to make a custom scenario so that i can run it e.g on a click of button. Any idea how can i do that? Any code example would also be helpful?

I tried inheriting the Scenario_Base class and created  one sample Randomizer and also coded all of the basic hooks e.g OnEnable, OnAwake()....OnScenarioEnd(). Buit i have no idea how to proceed further.